# Swift, Cocoapods and ios 7 compability, OAStackView

Tags: swift, ios7, cocoapods

Is it correctly understood that for cocoapods to work wih swift + ios 7 (and not get rejected in itunes submisson process) I can only use Objective-C frameworks/libraries such as OAStackView?

I believe the consensus is that if you try use anything swift through cocoapods it will only work in ios8+ but if if you have a swift project that uses objective-c things through cocoapods everything is fine?

What is very confusing to me is...

- OAStackView is built as a replacement for UIStackView so we can
  support ios7
- It supports cocoapods
- But XCode gives warning "Embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS8
  or later

So... Tha would indicate cocoapods can not be used in Swift projects targeting ios7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift libraries could be used only as frameworks. And frameworks are supported only in iOS 8 and later (with CocoaPods option use_frameworks). So the easiest way to support iOS 7 is to download library's source files and include them in your project.

You can check a possible workaround here https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2926#issuecomment-136766631 but I have not tried it myself yet.

Update:
If you have only Objective C libraries and support only iOS 8+ it is your choice whether to use use_frameworks or not. But to support also iOS 7 use_frameworks should be removed.

Comment: But OAStackView is an objecive-c library... (I use this as an example since it is very popular) So it should work accordingly to what I have read (yes, my own project is swift, but I am trying to use an objective-c library in it), but still gives the warning

Comment: @Tom Do you have `use_frameworks` line in your pod file? If yes - remove this line.

Comment: In my default podfile it states "Uncomment this line if you're using Swift" where the line underneath was "use_frameworks!" - hence I uncommented that line. Was that a mistake?

Comment: @Tom It means "uncomment this line if you're using Swift **libraries**". Since OAStackView is in Objective C you can (and you should to support iOS 7) leave this line commented.